# java:use 'Map' as value in another Java Map

Tags: java

I want to store a list of triad and my syntax is:

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer> > map;

map = new HashMap<Integer, TreeMap<Integer, Integer> >();
```

Then Java said:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from `HashMap<Integer,TreeMap<Integer,Integer>>` to `Map<Integer, Map<Integer,Integer>>`

What could I do?

Comment: You should declare `map` variable a `HasMap`: `HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer> > map;`

`map = new HashMap<Integer, TreeMap<Integer, Integer> >();`

Comment: `Map<Integer, ? extends Map<Integer, Integer> > map`

Comment: what's wrong with `map=new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer,Integer>>();` ?

Comment: The duplicate question is about lists rather than maps, but the explanation is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply type

```
map = new HashMap<>();
```